# Need a Regular Expression for the validation of Time format

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a datetime textbox which contains both date and time .
I want to validate the time.For the date i have validated.
e.g  datetime value is 04/23/2013 05:26 pm;

I need a regex which can validate the time that will be in format 00:00:00 .
all are digits and no special character or other than digits will be entered.
i want only to validate dd:dd:dd all are 2 digits.
I can enter for example 10:10:10 and 01:02.

i have tried with js way like this.i have no knowledge in regex.so i want suggestions.

```
function ValidateDate()
{
  //getting the value from textbox
  var dateVal=document.getElementById('txtDateTime').value;
  //after one space there is time..as i am using a datepicker and timepicker format
  var time=dateVal.split(' ')[1];   
  var isValidTime=CheckTime(time);
}


function CheckTime(time)
{
var timePart=time.split(":");
var hour = timePart[0];
var minute = timePart[1];
var second = timePart[2]; 


if((parseInt(hour,10)<0) || (parseInt(hour,10)>59))
{   
  return false;
}

if((parseInt(minute)>59) || (parseInt(minute)<0))
  {      
     return false;     

  }

 if((parseInt(second)<0) || (parseInt(second)>59))
  {
      return false;
  }  

  return true;
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: if there is one thing I have learned on stackoverflow, it is "no code no gain", I have been voted  down severally for no codes, so put up some codes you have worked on :-)

Comment: yeah and try googling it a bit first before you post..:)

Comment: @ShinTakezou you could post a basic answer (as a CW, if you don't want the rep) and downvote the question for the lack of research

Comment: I know I can. I just find some buzz unusefully pedant

Answer (score 5):

A simple regex of `/^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])(?::([0-5][0-9]))?$/g` will work.

```
10:00:00 - OK
01:00:00 - OK
60:00:00 - Fail
30       - Fail
30:00    - Fail
23:59    - OK
24:00    - Fail
23:60:60 - Fail
23:59:59 - OK
```

**Regex autopsy:**

- `^` - This is where the sentence MUST start
- `([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3])`

  - `[0-1][0-9]` - The digits `0` to `1` followed by any digit between `0` and `9`
  - `|` - OR
  - `2[0-3]` - The digit `2` followed by any digit between `0` and `3`
- `:` - A literal : character
- `([0-5][0-9])` - The digits from `0` to `5` followed by any digit between `0` and `9`
- `(?::([0-5][0-9]))?`

  - `?:` - a non capturing group
  - `:` - A literal : character
  - `([0-5][0-9])` - The digits from `0` to `5` followed by any digit between `0` and `9`
  - `?` - means that the previous statement should be there 0 or 1 time (so it doesn't *have* to be there).
- `$` - This is where the sentence MUST end

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should work: `/^\d{2}:\d{2}(?::\d{2})?$/`.

Comment: after reading the nice h2ooooooo's answer: this is not enough to validate the time: it just check it conforms to a format; then you have to do validation through code (for this, you could use capturing groups to get hh:mm(:ss)); with HTML5 there should be validation for the date type or even through patterns(regexp), but I think the support is not good enough for wide usage